# Svelte on:click event

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm new in developer and svelte and I'm trying to understand svelte/sveltekit doing simple roll dice game, pressing on roll dice button, dice image should change.

First of all I create a function who has supposed to get back an image based on random number

```
<script>
    let randomNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    function rollDice() {
        let randomImage = `/src/lib/images/dice-${randomNumber}.png`;
        return randomImage;
    }
</script>
```

Then I insert img and button

```
<img src="/src/lib/images/{randomNumber}" alt="Playing dice" class="dice" />


<button on:click={rollDice} class="btn btn--roll"> Roll dice</button>
```

Now when i press the button nothing happens and I can't understand what I didn't understand and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: have a look at this and see if it clears things up a bit https://svelte.dev/repl/366955bebdb94e2d84ea7ffc17c51139?version=3.58.0

Comment: or this https://svelte.dev/repl/e844002ad87e46779382470da05f186a?version=3.58.0

Comment: @Paolo just to clarify, I used:

```<img src={randomImage} alt="Playing dice" class="dice" />
```
I noticed that if I press the button very quickly, nothing happens. It is a Svelte behavior or is something I missed?

Comment: It's weird and I have no idea. Btw, for reactivity and such kind of knowledge, I'd suggest to have a look at the [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics), it's the gentle introduction you need at this point in time :-]

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the randomNumber and randomImage as a [reactive declaration](https://svelte.dev/examples/reactive-declarations).

The solution looks like this.

```html
<script>
  $: randomNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  $: randomImage = `/src/lib/images/dice-${randomNumber}.png`;
  function rollDice() {
       randomNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1
  }
</script>


<!-- <img src="/src/lib/images/{randomNumber}" alt="Playing dice" class="dice" /> -->

<p>
    randomNumber: {randomNumber}
</p>

<p>
    {randomImage}
</p>

<p>
    src = /src/lib/images/{randomNumber}
</p>

<button on:click={rollDice} class="btn btn--roll"> Roll dice</button>
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why you made randomNumber a reactive statement too? It shouldn't be required.

Comment: You are right! It's just me. If something is going to change, I like to have them with `$` syntax :).

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

Inside de onclick event so it rolls to a random number every time you click to roll.

Should work if

```
<script>
let randomNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
function rollDice() {
    randomNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    let randomImage = `/src/lib/images/dice-${randomNumber}.png`;
    return randomImage;
}
```

You'll maybe need to make it reactive too as the previous answer, but I don't think it'll need required.